Terminating subgroup of an upper central series of a finite group
Let $G$ be a finite group and $Z_0 = 1 \; \triangleleft \, Z_1 \, \triangleleft \, \cdots \, \triangleleft \, Z_r = Z_{r+1}$ be its upper central series.
If $G$ is nilpotent then $Z_r$ is actually $G$. But if $G$ is not nilpotent then $Z_r < G$.
In that case, does this subgroup have any additional nice properties? Specifically, is $Z_r$ always $\mathbf{F}(G)$, the fitting subgroup of $G$?
I can see that $Z_r \, \triangleleft \, G$ as it is characteristic, and although not entirely sure, seems like $Z_r$ is also nilpotent by the same upper central series $\implies$ $Z_r \subseteq \mathbf{F}(G)$.
Is it the case that $\mathbf{F}(G) \subseteq Z_r$? If so, how does one go about in proving it?

In $S_3$, the upper central series terminates in the trivial subgroup. But the fitting subgroup is $A_3$.

The upper central series of $Z_r$ is not generally the upper central series of $G$. But that series is a central series, so it proves $Z_r$ is nilpotent.

@ArturoMagidin, thanks for the help. In the 2nd comment did you mean the other way? i.e that the upper central series for $G$ is not a upper central series for $Z_r$ but a central series?

Both statements are true. E.g., if $Z_2\neq Z_1$, then $Z(Z_2)$ properly contains $Z(G)$. So the upper central series for $Z_r$ is not generally the (start of) the upper central series of $G$, and the start of the upper central series of $G$ os not generally the upper central series for $Z_r$.
